# Set window proportions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to set some proportions on a window, like height = half of width. I want to make it adaptive, because I have to consider multiple screen sizes. And I would manage it with a maximum height and width if the window is too big for the screen.

But I've searched on the web and found nothing :D

**Edit** :

I've tried `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` but as I have tabs, the window size changes regarding the tabs' content. If possible I would prefer a fixed size.

Comment: did you get the problem fixed?  I am interested to see what answer you came up with. please post your Answer and mark it as the answer if you don't see your answer below

Comment: please mark an answer, or post an answer that explains what you did to fix the problem and mark it as the answer for when someone else needs help with a similar problem

Answer (score 4):

How to Fetch the Current System Resolution in C#:

```
int hght = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
int wght = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
```

How to Set the height and width of the Form Size:

On Page_Load() event of the Form write the following code

```
this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
this.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height ;
```

[how to develop resolution independent Windows Applications in .NET](http://dotnetaid.com/2012/04/10/how-to-develop-resolution-independent-windows-application-in-net/)

Comment: You should not be posting link-only answers on SO.  Answers should be self contained and answer the question without *needing* to follow any links.  You should either quote/summarize relevant sections and provide the link for further details or simply post the link(s) as a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot comment on other posts yet. I do not have 50 rep. I did edit the answer.